# User.findAll is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

**This is my models/user.js**

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const User = sequelize.define('users', {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_name: DataTypes.DATE,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        instanceMethods: {
            generateHash(password) {
                return bcrypt.hash(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8));
            },
            validPassword(password) {
                return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
            }
        }
    });

    return User;
}
```

**This is my models/index.js**

```
module.exports = {
    User: require('./user')
  };
```

**This is my UserController.js**

```
var sequelize = require("sequelize");
var models = require("../models/index");

var userController = {};

// Show list of users
userController.list = function(req, res) {
 models.User.findAll()
  .then( userResponse => {
    res.status( 200 ).json( userResponse )
  })
  .catch( error => {
    res.status( 400 ).send( error )
  });
};
```

On executing the above code in localhost it is giving error that "User.findAll is not a function". I have tried in various ways but no result. Need help.
I am using express - nodejs - Sequelize(mysql2)

Comment: In `models/user.js` you export a function and not a User model.

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass a sequelize instance and a DataTypes to your User.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes)
```

So in order to do so you should change your models/index.js to something like this.

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var user = require("./user");
var sequelize = new Sequelize("your db config goes here");

module.exports = {
    User: user(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
}
```

And you don't need to require sequelize in every file, remove it from the controller and the model

There is an example repo [here](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example) that shows you how to use sequelize with express.js, we usually use a index.js like [this](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js) that will go through your models folder and you would be able to access the model using `db['User']`

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in index.js file. try by `sequelize init` that will create a a fully fledge `models/index.js` file automatically.

Then add this in your **UserController.js**

```
const db = require('../models/index');
const User = db['users'];
```

> Then you will be able to use User.findAll().

```
User.findAll()
  .then( userResponse => {
    res.status( 200 ).json( userResponse )
  })
```

Thanks